Why「记」for shop names?
The character「记」is often used with surnames in the names of shops, e.g.:

陈记[...] (陈记卤味)
王记[...] (王记牛肉面)
张记[...] (张记海鲜餐馆)

Dictionaries just generally say something similar to what Wiktionary says:

(Guangdong, Hong Kong, Taiwan) Suffix for restaurants, stores, etc.
李錦記 [Cantonese, trad.]
李锦记 [Cantonese, simp.]
lei5 gam2 gei3 [Jyutping]
Lee Kum Kee (food company founded by Lee Kum Sheung)

Ignoring the reach of the usage (HK, TW, etc.), as it is certainly much more widespread than that - there is little to no indication of why the character「记」is used.
Perhaps it is an extension of「记账」or something like that? But again the etymology is not alluded to in most reference works.
Ideas?

記 refers to "mark" as in 記號，記認，標記
A mark is used for people to identify a brand, store, or product
Examples:
陈记卤味, 王记牛肉面, 张记海鲜餐馆 all used the family name of the founder or owner as a mark for people to identify the product or restaurant
添記茶餐廳，強記士多，勝記燒臘 all used the given name of the founder or owner as a mark for people to identify the product or restaurant
I like 廖孖記腐乳 (The Liao Twin brand fermented bean curd) a lot

More example:
三花嘜 (three flowers mark)
三花為記 -  three flowers as its mark


I think xx记 here indicates the small commercial scale of such individual shop, compared with xx庄, xx堂, and 斋阁铺.
As for a clue why choosing the word 记, an infamous example is 認門前白兔兒為記 from 宋代, which got known by a modern Chinese exam.


“认门前白兔儿为记”,是告诉买家一定要认准本店的白兔捣药商标进行选购,这与现代的“请认准中国××商标”,似乎有异曲同工之妙
“认门前白兔儿为记” tells customers to recognize the white rabbit pounding medicine trademark of their store before purchasing, which is similar to the modern commercial ads “请认准中国××商标”.

